# how to search the given string in google using text input field?

Tags: html

Hi I am using this form code to enter get the text field. in that text field i will enter some string for search and i press submit button.when i click on submit button it show the search results in google search engine how to do this.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form name="input" action="index.html" method="get">
    Search:<input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks In advance......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply imitate how Google does it. The key items are the `action` attribute and the use of the name `q` for the string:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Google search</title>
<form action="http://www.google.com/search">
<label for=q>Keyword(s):</label>
<input type=text name=q size="32" id=q>
<input type="hidden" name="ie" value="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="oe" value="utf-8">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) for this.